# How to mark up the svg-file for drawing a route?

Tags: javascript, svg, inkscape

I have an inline svg file with a building plan. The plan contains rooms, halls, ect.

[image]

A room is closed poligon, i.e. finite sequence of segments. I need to draw a route from one room to another: from point A to point B.

[image: ![enter image description here]

The idea is to create [a mathematical graph from spatial data](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/network_analysis.html?highlight=topological%20tolerance). As a source we can use svg-objects. I am going to add circles inside rooms and connect their by one-segment paths. Circles become graph vertexes, and paths are graph edges. If several nodes have the same coordinates then they are the same graph vertex. So two paths that have a common node become connected to each other. All further actions will use this graph, not the svg-objects.

I am looking for an approach to markup the svg-file in order to proceed file with JavaScript.

**Question.** What are an potential problems in the proposed file markup?

One problem is a [topology tolerance](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/networkanalysis.html?highlight=topological%20tolerance). Two one-segment path with nodes closer than the specified tolerance are considered connected. How to define this tolerance?

Next problem deals with a segment's color. How to change the color of the one segment only?

Comment: Very confusing your question, you must consider tha you are talking about a very specific topic which touches svg almost by casuality, then you have to be more precise in your question. What are you trying to build and why? What would be the use of the svg path and what do you mean by edges? Sure if you clarify your question you'll get a better and faster answer.

Comment: I think you also need to reformulated your question's title because I thought it was a question about svg and it's not. What I understand by **mark-up the svg file** could be very different from what some else would understand. For me it seems to do something like building or editing the svg file on a text editor, but still unclear what kind of edition is required for your problem. So, if you better entitle your question to target people who knows what you are building then you'll find more accurate people who may help you. Then, as I can not catch up your problem, can go further helping you.